dll in nuget package are not copied to output with build
I have multiple project including nugets.
When i build the dll included in those nugets are NOT copied to output.
I tryed something i found online defining a file Directory.Build.props like this:

<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
    <WarningsAsErrors>NU1605</WarningsAsErrors>   
    <UseCommonOutputDirectory>true</UseCommonOutputDirectory>   
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>..\..\bin\</OutputPath>
    <DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>false</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemDefinitionGroup>
       <ProjectReference>
       <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
    <PackageReference>
       <PrivateAssets>none</PrivateAssets>
       <IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>
       <ExcludeAssets>none</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
 </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>

about the configurations above i tryed private assets to all too and some other variant..
How do i force msbuild to copy the dll of those nugets to my output when i build?
